# Ionic Pass value from ion select and ion datetime to calculate

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

[UI for my indexicator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6dDRp.png)

here is the UI for my project

hi all, i would like to ask if its possible for me to pass value based on the location and year? This is my first project in ionic which is a simple calculator but the amount to calculate is depends on the location and year.

For an example i put the rate as 10 then in the previous index, i chose location UK, the rate will be divided by 2 , then i put the year 2011, it will again divided by 2.

After that for the new index, i will repeat the input but now it will multiply based on selected location and year.

here is my .html for my rate, location and year. i also included a button that will show the total amount at the ion-input placeholder .

i have no idea what to code in my .ts

```
 <ion-list>


<ion-item> 
  <ion-label stacked>Rate</ion-label>
<ion-input type="text" text-right id="input" ></ion-input>
</ion-item>  

 <br>
 <br>
  <ion-list-header>Previous Index</ion-list-header>

 <ion-list>
  <ion-item>
   <ion-label>Location</ion-label>
  <ion-select value="50" okText="Okay" cancelText="Dismiss">
  <ion-select-option value="50">UK</ion-select-option>
  <ion-select-option value="70">US</ion-select-option>
  <ion-select-option value="30">Canada</ion-select-option>

   </ion-select>
 </ion-item>

</ion-list>
  <ion-item>
    <ion-label>Year</ion-label>
     <ion-datetime [pickerOptions]="customPickerOptions" placeholder="Select One" 
   displayFormat="YYYY" min="2011" max="2019"></ion-datetime>
    </ion-item>

 <ion-button type ="submit">Total</ion-button>


  <div class="window"></div>
  <div class="input"><span>
      <ion-input type="text" placeholder="0" name="display">
      </ion-input>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your html should look like this,

```
 <ion-item>
    <ion-label>Location</ion-label>
    <ion-select (change)="onSelectionChanges($event)" [(ngModel)]="currentSelection" okText="Okay" cancelText="Dismiss">
          <ion-select-option selected="true" value="50">UK</ion-select-option>
          <ion-select-option value="70">US</ion-select-option>
          <ion-select-option value="30">Canada</ion-select-option>
    </ion-select>
 </ion-item>
```

And you can bind some onChange event to the ion-select. and trigger some method Eg: onSelectionChanges()

```
export class Example{
    currentSelection = '50';

    onSelectionChanges(event: any) {
        // Your logic to apply when selection happens, goes here
        //You can also get the value in the variable currentSelection
        console.log(this.currentSelection);
        //another way is to access the changed value from event
        console.log(event.target.value);
    }
}
```